# displaying a template/layout from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following associations

```
 Group:
   has_many :group_links, :dependent => :destroy

 GroupLink:
    belongs_to :group
```

I want to display all the group links which belong to a particular group inside a layout which includes other objects which are not visible from inside GroupLInks views. SO I want to render a template from the GroupController as follows:

```
     def group_links
          @group_links = @group.group_links.all
          render :template => 'group_links/group_links', :layout => 
                              '/layouts/sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu'
     end
```

But I get the following error:

```
       The action 'index' could not be found for GroupLinksController
```

If I create a 'index' view for GroupLinks and try to display it inside a layout with other objects, it throws the error

```
      "You have a nil object"
```

I have the following method to initialize inside my groupscontroller:

```
    def init_group
      @group = Group.find_by_id(params[:id])
      @group_blog_tags=@group.blog.blog_posts.tag_counts
      @booth_links = @group.group_links.all
      max_id = Group.count_by_sql("select min(profile_id) from (select profile_id from 
               group_memberships where group_id = #{@group.id} order by profile_id desc 
               limit 200) as x")
      @booth_members = @group.members.all(:conditions => "profiles.id >= #
      {rand(max_id)+1}", :limit => 20).to_a.sort! { |a,b| rand(3)-1 }
    redirect_to groups_explorations_path unless @group
   end
```

These other objects are used in the groups layouts to display the other objects. The thing is I was able to display another object from the GroupsController, without needing any index action inside that objects Controller. I have the exact same setup for GroupLinks as well but it does not work in this case...Please can you help me resolve this?

Comment: did you created rout for group_links action, your link is directed to index action of GroupLinksController and not intended group_links

Comment: Yes actually I have it like this: Inside GroupsController I have the action: def get_group_links booth_links = group.group_links.all           render :template => 'group_links/group_links', :layout =>                                 '/layouts/sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu'
          end, and inside routes I have the following resources :groups do member do get :get_group_links  resources :group_links end

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that @group is nil in your controller method group_links.
You can try to make like this:

```
def group_links
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])  
    @group_links = @group.group_links.all
    render :template => 'group_links/group_links', :layout => 
                      '/layouts/sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu'
end
```

But I'm not sure that this will work correctly:

```
render :template => 'group_links/group_links', :layout => 
                      '/layouts/sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu'
```

You can try just put your template in correct view folder with name "group_links" and match in your routes.rb file.

Comment: Hi Mosin, @group is known because I have initialized it inside init_groups method which I use as: before_filter :init_group, :except => [:create, :new] so I dont think its because it cant find it. As for the render template, as I said I used a similar call in another method where it works properly as expected :( I have no idea where else to look?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had not put the proper path for this method in my layout. The routes were fine but the call to this method was not - I had to break my head to find it :(...Thanks for your time @Mosin and @RubyMan, appreciate it!